# How to filter out empty flux

Tags: project-reactor, reactive, reactor

For example, I have the following code which creates a Mono with a list of 3 numbers `1,2,3`. I want to filter out the number `1`. The result would be a list of 2 numbers `2,3`. What should I do in the `flatMapMany` so that it skip the number `1`?

```
Mono.just(new LinkedList<>{{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
}})
.flatMapMany(number -> {
  if (number == 1) {
    // not return 
  }

  return number;
})
.collectList()
.map(numbers -> {
  // numbers should be 2,3
})
```

A follow-up question

what if in my code I return `Flux.empty()` when number is 1

```
.flatMapMany(number -> {
  if (number == 1) {
    return Flux.empty() 
  }

  return number;
})
 .filter(i ->{
  // how to filter out Flux.empty() ?
})
```

In the filter, how can I detect if `i` is empty flux and filter it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this example. You can use `flatMapIterable` to convert a mono of list to Flux.

```
    Mono.just(List.of(1,2,3))
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())    
        .filter(i -> i != 1)
        .collectList()
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s)); //prints [2,3]
```

---

For the follow up question. We need to use `.handle` which is a combination of map and filter methods.

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1, 2, 3))
                .handle((number, sink) -> {
                    if (number != 1) {
                        sink.next(number);
                    }
                })
                .collectList()
                .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

If you really want to go with your approach, then we need to filter like this

```
    Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1, 2, 3))
            .flatMap((number) -> number == 1 ? Flux.empty() : Flux.just(number))
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added a follow-up question. Can you shed some light?

Comment: note that comparing Flux instances like that is generally discouraged, as eg. the empty() factory method could return a fresh instance in the future

Comment: @SimonBaslé, honestly I did not like this either. Handle is the right choice. But do we have any way to filter the empty object ?

Comment: in a flatMap, returning an empty publisher effectively filters itself, as it is as if nothing was propagated. it is equivalent to ignoring the source element